# Реализация галочки "Чужой компьютер"

Tags: php, html

сразу хочу извиниться если кому-то этот вопрос покажется абсурдным, но я никак не могу понять как работает логика галочки чужой компьютер. Можете скинуть пример или просто написать что должно происходить при нажатии галочки.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538226/how-does-the-remember-my-password-checkbox-work

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вопрос таки несколько в другом.

Comment: Есть инфа что `Чужой компьютер` это аналог `Инкогнито`. Т.е. вся URL-история, все картинки и прочие вложения - ничего не будет сохранено после того как вы закроете вкладку. Это галочка сделана для неопытных пользователей пк (которые не умеют и не знают про этот режим), но хотят чтобы ничего не было сохранено на компьютере после их выхода.

Comment: Я правильно понял что тут нужно работать с куки ?
Возможно ли реализовать галочку с помощью сессии или обязательно с куки ?

Answer (score 2):

В session это можно реализовать, как вариант ты можешь просто поставить время истечения сесии к примеру через 10 минут, после старта сесии начнется автоматический обратный отсчет и при времени истечения, пользователя просто выбросит из личного кабинета, даже если он из него не выходил, а данные для входа не сохранятся.

```
 '''
```

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 72800);
1 день = 86400 секунд
2 дня = 172800 секунд
3 дня = 259200 секунд
1 неделя = 604800 секунд
'''